# C99 Array Initialization

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, c99

I must use C99 but need to initialize a really sparse array. Something along the lines of:

```
struct MyStruct1
{
    uint8_t Id;
    char Name[20];
};

struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1List[50][512];

MyStruct1List[1][0] = {0, ""};
MyStruct1List[1][10] = {45, "asb"};

MyStruct1List[5][20] = {20, "dfsdf"};

MyStruct1List[19][70] = {987, "fgfdg"};
```

Obviously the above doesn't work. What is the best way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

In C99 you may use designated initializers.  I would generally recommend it for `struct` members anyway since it is explicit.  For example:

```
struct MyStruct1 MyStruct1List[50][512] =
{
    [1][0]   = {.Id = 0,   .Name = ""     },
    [1][10]  = {.Id = 45,  .Name = "asb"  },
    [5][20]  = {.Id = 20,  .Name = "dfsdf"},
    [19][70] = {.Id = 987, .Name = "fgfdg"}
};
```

As noted in the comments, this may require a large amount of ROM due to storing zeros for members not explicitly initialized.

Another option would be to use compound literal expressions to assign members individually:

```
MyStruct1List[1][0]   = (struct MyStruct1 ){.Id = 0,   .Name = ""     };
MyStruct1List[1][10]  = (struct MyStruct1 ){.Id = 45,  .Name = "asb"  };
MyStruct1List[5][20]  = (struct MyStruct1 ){.Id = 20,  .Name = "dfsdf"};
MyStruct1List[19][70] = (struct MyStruct1 ){.Id = 987, .Name = "fgfdg"};
```

In this case, you will probably want to use a nested for loops to initialize the rest of the contents of the array to a known value prior to assigning individual members.

Comment: This has a substantial difference in most implementations: the entire contents of the struct will have to be loaded from the executable, so the executable will increase in size by 525 KiB.  In contrast, OP's version might require just a few bytes of code and data to initialize the specific elements at runtime.